# makefile: second dependency not execute

Tags: makefile

Second dependency in goal `first-deploy` not executed.

if I execute `make first-deploy`, make execute only first dependence - `build-proxy-base` with success result and exit.

Makefile:

```sh
UID=`id -u`
GID=`id -g`

NODE_N=node
PROXY_N=proxy
PY_N=py

DOCKER_D=docker
PROXY_D=skif-proxy
NODE_D=skif
PY_D=skif-proxy/template-service

# first is default
default: first-deploy docker-compose-up

docker-compose-up:
    cd $(DOCKER_D) && \
        docker-compose up --build && \
        cd ..

build-docker-base:
    docker build \
        --build-arg UID=${UID} \
        --build-arg GID=${GID} \
        -f ${D}/Dockerfile.base \
        --rm \
        -t skif-${SERV_N}-base ${D}

build-node-base: D := ${NODE_D}
build-node-base: SERV_N := ${NODE_N}
build-node-base: build-docker-base

build-proxy-base:D=${PROXY_D}
build-proxy-base:SERV_N=${PROXY_N}
build-proxy-base: build-docker-base

build-py-base: D=${PY_D}
build-py-base: SERV_N=${PY_N}
build-py-base: build-docker-base

first-deploy: build-proxy-base build-py-base build-node-base
```

**UPD**
I understand that `build-docker-base` build only once, but how I can reuse it code in 2 goals with other paramethers?

Comment: Is this really the complete `makefile`?

Comment: @G.M., no, updated makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make definitely considered the second dependency.  If it didn't "execute" then it means make decided nothing needed to be done to execute it.

I can see this:

```
build-proxy-base: build-docker-base
  ...
build-node-base: build-docker-base
```

Both of these targets list the same target as a prerequisite, and they don't do anything else.  In make, a given target (like `build-docker-base`) will only ever be built one time by make per invocation.  Once make builds it once, it will be considered up to date no matter how many other targets may depend on it.

So make considers `build-node-base`, sees that it was already brought up to date due to `build-proxy-base`, and decides there's nothing else to do.

Since you don't actually show us to `build-node-base` rule or explain what you're trying to do, there's not much more we can say for sure.

*ETA* Based on your updated makefile, it seems like you're trying to think of targets as if they were functions, that can be called by listing them as prerequisites.  They are not, and they cannot.

It looks to me like you just want to run the same recipe multiple times with different parameters.  I think you should just write it like this:

```
build-node-base build-proxy-base build-py-base:
        docker build \
            --build-arg UID=${UID} \
            --build-arg GID=${GID} \
            -f ${D}/Dockerfile.base \
            --rm \
            -t skif-${SERV_N}-base ${D}

build-node-base: D := ${NODE_D}
build-node-base: SERV_N := ${NODE_N}

build-proxy-base:D=${PROXY_D}
build-proxy-base:SERV_N=${PROXY_N}

build-py-base: D=${PY_D}
build-py-base: SERV_N=${PY_N}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I looked for.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no recipe for either `build-proxy-base` or `build-node-base`, and both are effectively phony, it's unclear how you are concluding that `build-node-base` is not, in fact, built.

I suspect that the actual observation is that target `build-docker-base` is built only once per `make` run, and that that build reflects the values of variables `D` and `SERV_N` set while building `build-proxy-base`.  That has little to do with whether target `build-node-base` is built, and a lot to do with the fact that `make` builds each target at most once per run.

Comment: Sorry. Update makefile.

Comment: @tannerman, the added makefile details make no difference whatever to this answer.  They neither clarify your claim nor demand any changes to what I've already said.

Comment: ok, `build-docker-base` build once. So how  can I avoide code dubling (reuse `build-docker-base` with paramethers) ?

Comment: Sorry, SO is flipping around the answers and I edited the wrong one :(