# Make only running first listed dependency

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm writing a makefile that accepts three targets:

```
make build-consul
make build-envoy

make build # (builds both)
```

The `build-consul`/`build-envoy` tasks work as expected on their own.  However, the `build` task only runs the first dependency.  Consider the following Makefile:

```
%consul: APP=consul
%envoy: APP=envoy

build-consul: _build
build-envoy: _build

build: build-consul build-envoy
_build:
  echo building $(APP)
```

The output of running the `build` target is:

```
$ make build
echo working on consul
working on consul
```

Why is only the first dependency `build-consul` being run, but the second `build-envoy` dependency is ignored?  It appears that whatever dependency is listed first for the `build` task is always run (if I swap them, then `envoy` is the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because both `build-consul` and `build-envoy` do nothing on their own. They both depend on a separate target `_build` which will always be executed once. When `make` visits `build-consul` it remakes `_build` target (since the file probably does not exist) and when later it comes to `build-envoy` it does not remake `_build` target, since this was already made. See for yourself:

```
$ make build -dr
Considering target file 'build'.
 File 'build' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'build'.
 No implicit rule found for 'build'.
  Considering target file 'build-consul'.
   File 'build-consul' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'build-consul'.
   No implicit rule found for 'build-consul'.
    Considering target file '_build'.
     File '_build' does not exist.
     Finished prerequisites of target file '_build'.
    Must remake target '_build'.
echo building consul
Putting child 0x55931292b870 (_build) PID 8627 on the chain.
Live child 0x55931292b870 (_build) PID 8627
building consul
Reaping winning child 0x55931292b870 PID 8627
Removing child 0x55931292b870 PID 8627 from chain.
    Successfully remade target file '_build'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'build-consul'.
  Must remake target 'build-consul'.
  Successfully remade target file 'build-consul'.
  Considering target file 'build-envoy'.
   File 'build-envoy' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'build-envoy'.
   No implicit rule found for 'build-envoy'.
    Pruning file '_build'.                            <--- Already built, not making again
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'build-envoy'.
  Must remake target 'build-envoy'.
  Successfully remade target file 'build-envoy'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'build'.
Must remake target 'build'.
Successfully remade target file 'build'.
```

You can make it work without additional target, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
%consul: APP=consul
%envoy: APP=envoy

.PHONY: build
build: build-consul build-envoy

.PHONY: build-consul build-envoy
build-consul build-envoy:
        echo building $(APP)
```

`.PHONY` is to make sure the target is built even when the file of the same name exists (good practice).

Output:

```
$ make build
echo building consul
building consul
echo building envoy
building envoy
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice you were specifying `make build` as your command line.

In that case, see this answer: [makefile: second dependency not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200795/makefile-second-dependency-not-execute/62201033#62201033)

Comment: Isn't that the equivalent of what I have? `build: build-consul build-envoy`.  I'm not using the default target, I'm specifying the target on the command line `make build`.